# TFS2015 build agent cannot sync repository

Tags: tfs, version-control, build-automation, tfs-2015, tfvc

I am trying to set up build automation (it will be for CI in the future, but at the moment I'm queuing builds manually) on a TFS 2015 server, using the newer method, not the old XAML method. I have a build agent installed and registered (which seems to have gone okay), but every time I try and queue a build, it will fail when syncing the repository with the message "Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed."

- The user that the build agent service is running as has access to the TFS repository.
- As far as I know, there is no proxy between the build agent and the server.
- The server is within the same network as the build agent; it is not Team Services.
- The agent version is 1.83.2

What should I be looking for to fix this? The log is below:

```
2017-06-28T15:14:02.4032890Z Starting: Get sources
2017-06-28T15:14:02.4188890Z Entering TfvcSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2017-06-28T15:14:02.4188890Z localPath=C:\TFSBuildAgent\WorkFolder\ff694322\SCR
2017-06-28T15:14:02.4188890Z clean=False
2017-06-28T15:14:02.4188890Z sourceVersion=C13590
2017-06-28T15:14:02.4188890Z mappingJson={"mappings":[{"serverPath":"$/SCR","mappingType":"map"},{"serverPath":"$/SCR/Drops","mappingType":"cloak"}]}
2017-06-28T15:14:02.4188890Z Syncing repository: SCR (TFVC)
2017-06-28T15:14:02.4188890Z workspaceName=ws_ff694322_3
2017-06-28T15:14:03.5264910Z Workspace Name: ws_ff694322_3;Build\a2dd1d8a-5146-47c6-bda1-6f761cddeecd
2017-06-28T15:14:13.0113076Z ##[error]Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
2017-06-28T15:14:13.0425077Z ##[error]Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
```

Comment: Does your organization use any proxies?

Comment: Not that I know of between the build agent and the TFS server. The server is on-premises, not Team Services. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Try to setup a new build agent and try again to check whether the issue persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try below ways to narrow down the issue:

- Please check your TFS version, the agent version 1.83.2 is for
  TFS 2015 RTM. if your TFS is not 2015 RTM , suggest you update the
  agent to the [specific version](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v1-windows#what-version-of-the-agent-runs-with-my-version-of-tfs).
- Check the event viewer on the TFS server if there are some related
  error info.
- Try to set other accounts which can get the
  sources as the agent service account.
- Try to deploy a new agent to check this issue again.
- If you are using Window Server 2008R2, just try to apply the [HotFix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981898/a-file-does-not-download-from-an-iis-7.5-server-that-is-running-window) and try the workaround.

Comment: It may be that the hotfix is required. There are other things happening (e.g. new users unable to sync the repository using Visual Studio, same error) that suggest that's the cause, but I can't get it installed for a day or two. I'll let you know what happens when it's installed.

Comment: @Richard Ward Have you resolved the issue by applying the hotfix?

Comment: Still waiting on getting it installed, I'm afraid.

Comment: It wasn't the hotfix that solved it exactly - there were some updates that hadn't been installed. Installing those let the repository sync, though I still have to do some tweaking to stop it failing in other ways now. Thanks for the help!